Getting `Unsupported request - method type: post` when trying to create an ad account with the Facebook API
I'm trying to create an ad account in my Facebook Business with this API endpoint:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/
I'm using these parameters for my API call:
{
  "name": "Graph API Test 123",
  "currency": "EUR",
  "timezone_id": "42",
  "end_advertiser": "{my_business_id}",
  "media_agency": "{my_fb_app_id}",
  "partner": "NONE",
  "funding_id": "{my_funding_id}"
}

According to the docs, a POST endpoint is available and valid.

When removing the funding ID from my request it works. I've checked if the payment method behind the funding ID is active and valid and it is. It's assigned to other ad accounts as well and I'm spending money with it.
Does anyone know why this happens? I'm pretty sure it used to work in the past.

The valid parameters listed on that page, for creating an ad account, don't contain any mention of funding_id.

@C3roe I see the funding_id parameter being shown in the API docs for the POST request. I've attached a screenshot to my question

I've reported the problem in the Facebook developer forum (where you can get in touch with the Facebook tech support). Turned out it was a Facebook bug and they fixed it. Link: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/368687739616595/#_=_
